# Input submit didn't submit form with jquery in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, internet-explorer

I create a HTML and jQuery code to submit a form with jQuery and it works in all browsers except Internet Explorer.

HTML:

```
<form name="file_upload" id="file_upload" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>projects/file" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
    <a class="button" onclick="document.getElementById('file-upload-input').click(); return false;"><span class="plus"></span>Upload File</a> 
    <input id="file-upload-input" name="upload" type="file" style="display:none;">
    <input id="submit-button" name="submit" type="submit" value="Upload" style="display:none;">
</form>
```

jQuery

```
$(document)
.on('change', '#file-upload-input', function(){
    $('#submit-button').click();
})
```

**EDIT**: I have also tried :

```
$(document)
.on('change', '#file-upload-input', function(){
    $("#file_upload").submit();
})
```

But the input submit didn't submit a form only in Internet Explorer.

Comment: Close your inputs before going any further.  It may be as simple as that - `<input id="file-upload-input" name="upload" type="file" style="display:none;" />` (notice  />)

Comment: Archer, thanks for comment. I did it before, but It didn't work.

Comment: As long as you've kept it like that then it's fine - you need to rule that out.  You should also update the code above to reflect it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
$(document)
.on('change', '#file-upload-input', function(){
    $("#file_upload").submit();
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Changing:

```
$('#submit-button').click();
```

to:

```
$('#file_upload').submit();
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You might have problems when using delegated events approach with 'change' event in IE (since it doesn't support bubbling which events delegation relies on).

Try binding onchange handler directly to file input:

```
$('#file-upload-input').on('change', function(){
    $("#file_upload").submit();
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's the event delivery what limit some operation that fired by javascript.
So you should always use original event what fired by the browser,In your case,we can use css to make the file upload input to transparent and covered it to the 'a' button:

```
<input id="file-upload-input" name="upload" type="file" style="
width: 88px;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
opacity: 0;
filter:alpha(opacity=0)
">
```

If this works,you can delete the onclick event what is binded to the 'a' node

Comment: Even this idea didn't fix the problem. I dont really know where can be the problem :S